# USB audio interface (sound card) found in USB list but not as sound card

Tags: linux, usb, audio, drivers

Here is my situation. I've been using windows for years. I'm switching to linux (brand new **Ubuntu 20.04**). And I have an issue with sound.

My set up is made of an **integrated sound card** on my mother board (Asus P5N-D) which I never use but is recognized and work well on Ubuntu. (But doesn't feed my needs still.)
I also have an **external audio interface** (a Lexicon IO42 which is not on the list of ALSA hardware compliance but cost me more than 350 bucks...) to manage 4 inputs and output the sound on monitoring speakers (thoses that can not be plugged to the integrated sound card, and need a more "pro like" interface).

I tried every procedures described in the Ubuntu Help. I ended with the two final sentences : "ask some help on forums to install specific drivers or buy a new sound card." As you can expect, I prefer asking you before going back on windows since buying a new card is not an option.

Here is what I tried : 
`lsusb`
which gave me :

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1210:0018 DigiTech Lexicon IO42
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 045e:076c Microsoft Corp. Comfort Mouse 4500
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:c318 Logitech, Inc. Illuminated Keyboard
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

(See the Bus 001 ? The DigiTech Lexicon OI42 thing ?)

When I ask
`cat /proc/asound/cards`
I get :

```
0 [NVidia_1       ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                      HDA NVidia at 0xfe024000 irq 22
 1 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                      HDA NVidia at 0xfbffc000 irq 16
```

Which are the integrated sound card outputs.

Not surprisingly a `aplay -l` gives :

```
**** Liste des Périphériques Matériels PLAYBACK ****
carte 0: NVidia_1 [HDA NVidia], périphérique 0: ALC883 Analog [ALC883 Analog]
  Sous-périphériques: 0/1
  Sous-périphérique #0: subdevice #0
carte 0: NVidia_1 [HDA NVidia], périphérique 1: ALC883 Digital [ALC883 Digital]
  Sous-périphériques: 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0: subdevice #0
carte 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], périphérique 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Sous-périphériques: 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0: subdevice #0
carte 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], périphérique 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Sous-périphériques: 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0: subdevice #0
carte 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], périphérique 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Sous-périphériques: 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0: subdevice #0
```

My Lexicon product is discontinued. The manufacturer provides Windows and MacOS drivers (but not even for the latest MacOS version).

What should I try ? Is there a way to make my workstation sound again ?

Thank you in advance for your help and advises !

Comment: Post info what the dmesg command says about that device. It seems to be detected just fine as a USB device, but if there is no driver for it, it won't know what to do with it and it won't show up as an audio device.

Comment: The `dmesg | grep Lexicon` gives `[ 1014.184956] usb 1-3: Product: Lexicon IO42
[ 1014.184958] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: Lexicon`

Comment: Your system has at least three audio devices, one is on-board intergrated (likely Realtek), the other one is your USB Lexicon, and the third one is inside your NVDA video card supporting embedded audio channels via HDMI. You need to decide what you want to use, and obviously you need Linux Driver for your "lexicon" device. I feel somehow that your device does not follow USB Audio Class specifications, so good luck with Linux.